# Неведомое появление No message found under code 'home' for locale 'ru_RU'

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jsp, spring-mvc, i18n

Использую Spring MVC, сервер Tomcat 7.

При локализации сайта возникает ошибка 
*HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'home' for locale 'ru_RU'.*
НО я не использую русскую локализацию вообще только английский и украинский. Соответственно есть два файла messages_en.properties и messages_ua.properties.

Данная ошибка возникает только на первой страницы которая указана в  на других же страницах все нормально, и смена сообщений происходит правильно.

Код -servlet.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" id="messageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:/messages"></property>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"></property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" id="localeChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang"></property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver" id="localeResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"></property>
</bean>
```

На странице index.jsp выводится `<spring:message code="home"/>`.

Очищать кеш Inteliji, chrome, tomcat пробовала - не помогло.

Ссылка на гит с проектом https://github.com/seltsamD/trouble_localization

Comment: С какой локалью запущена JVM? С каким языком браузер запрашивает страницу?

Comment: JVM - uk_UA, а браузеры проверяла разные: chrome  с английский просит русский, Edge c русским просит английский.

Comment: Скорее всего не поможет, но попробуйте довавить `<property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="false"></property>` в обьявление бина `messageSource`. Также советую переименовать `messages_en.properties` в `messages.properties`.

Comment: Увы не помогло. .properies переименовала и добавила ru_RU локализацию, но ошибка остается все той же.

Comment: Ну тогда только дебажить. У вас есть возможность дать доступ к исходникам или создать тестовый проект в котором бы данная ошибка проявлялась?

Comment: Ссылка на гит с проектом https://github.com/seltsamD/trouble_localization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка связана с настройками IntelliJ IDEA. Так как вы для разработки использовали Utlimate Edition, то мне не удалось нормально запустить ваше приложение на Community Edition. К сожалению, ваш проект никак иначе запустить нельзя. Мне пришлось править проект, чтобы сделать из него web-приложение с точки зрения Maven. После этого я смог задеплоить его в Tomcat, но в такой конфигурации ошибка не воспроизвелась.

Итого, я вам советую преобразовать ваше приложение в нормальное web-приложение чтобы оно могло запускаться в любом другом окружении. Это вам в любом случае понадобится, если вы захотитие запускать его где-либо еще кроме вашего компьютера.

Comment: Спасибо! 
Переписав приложение с аннотациями вместо .xml все заработало.